# Flake8: how to select all lints

Tags: python, lint, flake8

According to:
https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/6.0.0/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-select

> --select=<errors>
>
> Specify the list of error codes you wish Flake8 to report. Similarly to --ignore. You can specify a portion of an error code to get all that start with that string. For example, you can use E, E4, E43, and E431.
>
> This defaults to: E,F,W,C90

I'm currently using:

> select = B,C,E,F,W,T4,B9,N8,E4

My question is: **is there any shortcut to select all lints?**. I want this to write a bot (POC) to auto report issues (possibly ignoring project preferences) and I don't want to launch a new version of bot if a new select was added to flake8.

I'm expecting something simple like `--select='*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to select all errors and disable all off-by-default errors while ignoring the configuration you need to combine two options:

- `--isolated`: ignore the configuration
- `--ignore=`: reset the ignore list to be empty

you do not need to adjust `--select` as it will contain everything by default

you would also need to find any `off_by_default = True` plugins and enable each of them through `--enable-extensions`

note that this doesn't necessarily turn on all errors as plugins can decide whether to report things based on other conditions.  the builtin `mccabe` plugin for instance will not report `C90` unless `--max-complexity` is specified and `pycodestyle` will not report (idk the error code because I think it's a bad one) unless `--max-doc-length` is specified

---

disclaimer: I maintain flake8 and a few plugins

Comment: The doc says that `--select` defaults to `E,F,W,C90` and you are saying `you do not need to adjust --select as it will contain everything by default`

Comment: with no plugins, yes

Comment: OK, I tested here, without `--select`, flake8 will enable everything like you said

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use --select at all. By default it will select all the errors to test for linting.
In general, use --select only if you know specifically which errors you want to test, and use --ignore only if there are specific tests you don't want to run.

Comment: So, are you saying that docs are wrong? doc says `This defaults to: E,F,W,C90`

Comment: I tested here, and you are right.